# PaymentIntent status: requires_source_action for Stripe ACH implementation on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have been trying to complete a test PaymentIntent for ACH implementation.
I was able to create the PaymentIntent using:

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  {
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
    confirm: true,
    payment_method_types: ['us_bank_account'],
    on_behalf_of: 'acct_XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    mandate_data: {
      customer_acceptance: {
        type: 'offline'   
      },   
    },
    payment_method_data: {
      type: 'us_bank_account',
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Test Name'
      },
      us_bank_account: {
        routing_number: '110000000',
        account_number: '000123456789',
        account_holder_type: 'individual'
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Following this, I hit the PaymentConfirm API:

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(
  'pi_3MosEfLYIdOgExxxxxxxxxx',
  {payment_method: 'pm_1MosEfLYIdOgE1Qxxxxxx'},
)
```

The confirmation is reflected on my sandbox dashboard but the payment status is still incomplete.PaymentIntent status is:requires_source_action
[image: Stripe Sandbox Dashboard]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be using an older API version as on this API [upgrade](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-11),the `requires_source_action status`  is now `requires_action`. You can also confirm the current possible statuses on Payment Intents [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-status).

As to why you’re getting this error, you’d want to look at how [ACH Direct Debit works](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit). ACH Direct Debit requires you to collect a mandate AND the bank accounts must be verified. My suspicion is that the payment method has not been verified yet and you can look at the `next_action` as [specified](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action) on your screenshot. When present/ if present, this tells you what actions you need to take next.

I highly recommend that you follow this guide for accepting [ACH Direct Debit payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API).

Comment: I did send the mandate, it turns out that all I had to do is mimic micro deposits through API and the payment was complete